# how to parse xml from EditText?

Tags: android

i try to build an application with xml parser.

ex : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

but i want to parse xml file from EditText, how it work ?

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean parse XML File from EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to parse XML, the most widely used being SAX and DOM. The choice is quite strategical [as explained in this paper](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/books/xmljava/chapters/ch09s11.html).

Here is a short explanation of SAX:

- You will need some `import`s:

  ```
  import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
  import android.util.Xml;
  ```
- Create your own XML SAX [DefaultHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html):

  ```
  class MySaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {
      // Override the methods of DefaultHandler that you need.
      // See [this link][3] to see these methods.
      // These methods are going to be called while the XML is read
      // and will allow you doing what you need with the content.
      // Two examples below:

      public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
           // This is called each time an openeing XML tag is read.
           // As the tagname is passed by parameter you know which tag it is.
           // You also have the attributes of the tag.
           // Example <mytag myelem="12"> will lead to a call of
           // this method with the parameters:
           // - localName = "mytag"
           // - attributes = { "myelem", "12" }  
      }

      public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
           // This is called each time some text is read.
           // As an example, if you have <myTag>blabla</myTag>
           // this will be called with the parameter "blabla"
           // Warning 1: this is also called when linebreaks are read and the linebreaks are passed
           // Warning 2: you have to memorize the last open tag to determine what tag this text belongs to (I usually use a stack).
      }
  }
  ```
- Extract the XML as a `String` from the `EditText`. Let's call it `xmlContent`
- Create and initialize your XML parser:

  ```
  final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes()));
  final MySaxHandler handler = new MySaxHandler();
  ```
- And then, make the XML content to be read by the parser. This will lead your `MySaxHandler` to have its various method called while the reading is in progress.

  ```
  Xml.parse(reader, handler);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

to

```
String xmlString = editText.getText().toString();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
xr.parse(new InputSource(reader));
```